# JavaFX Grid Pane - Set a row's height to be the same as a column's width?

Tags: javafx, size, rows, fxml, gridpane

Here is the definition for my grid pane:

```
<GridPane fx:id="theGrid" hgap="5.0" vgap="5.0">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints fx:id="theColumn" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints fx:id="theRow" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="NEVER" />
  </rowConstraints>
</Gridpane>
```

I am trying to bind the row height to the column width so that the cell is perfectly square. I have tried to do this as below but with no success:

```
<RowConstraints fx:id="theRow" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="${theColumn.prefWidth}" vgrow="NEVER" />
```

Could someone please let me know if this can be done, thanks.

Comment: Don't know why your direct binding in fxml is not working. Did you try to create a binding in the underlying init method of the controller?

Comment: @Inge I did not, how would I do that?